# What is the next number in the sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]What is the next number in the sequence ?

1
1 1
2 1
1 2 1 1
1 1 1 2 2 1
3 1 2 2 1 1
1 3 1 1 2 2 1

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Be sure to read [how to ask](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you provide some perspective on this question? What do you think the next number is?

Comment: Any answer is good, e.g. $1112112111112213122111311221 + 1 = 1112112111112213122111311222$. If you would like to guess what the author intention was, try writing it in several lines like this "1", "1 1", "2 1", "1 2 1 1", and so on... (I won't give you the exact method.)

Comment: @dtldarek It may help to read the lines out loud.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is called the reading sequence or something similar.

Your first term is 1.

The next term is just counting how many ones there are in the previous term. So it says "one 1" or "11".

The next term reads that there are "two 1s" or "21".

The next one says "One 2 and one 1" or "1211".

Just bunching up together just complicates things.
Can you take this forward to find the term you want?

Comment: I believe your logic is correct and it will provide the answer . Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

http://oeis.org/A005150 all terms put together to form one long sequence.

http://oeis.org/A034002 it's actually already on there, didn't know that.